# Cannot write DVDs anymore, but can read them and write CDs

Tags: troubleshooting, dvd, burning, optical-drive

I'm stumped. I used to be able to write to DVDs and now I can't. I've tried different media (Memorex and Imations) I've tried different drives (internal and external)  and even different OS's (Windows 7 and Linux Mint). Nothing I've done will work and it's a real problem not being able to burn DVD's.

I'm on an Acer 6930 if that helps.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So the only remaining factor is the laptop itself?

Comment: That's what I was wondering, if there could be something wrong with the SATA channel or something?

Comment: Perhaps - can you connect it to a different channel or perhaps use another cable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my desktop PC a few months ago. I asked about the problem on SuperUser but no one could find what the problem was. Most probably, it was something related to SATA data channels or motherboard. I ended up selling that PC and buying a new one instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm wondering. But what about an external USB DVD Writer? How come if it's a bad SATA would the USB be bad?

Comment: I wish I knew... but IMHO, it must be something to do with the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the lens responsible for writing has conked off. Try writing on another ( or a friend's ) system. If it doesn't work, try borrowing a friend's DVD writer and connect it to your system and try writing. If this works its pretty much safe to say that the writer has past its prime and time to get a new one.

Comment: I've already tried different drives with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you read DVDs with it?

I seem to recall that DVD/CD writers have different laser/lenses for DVD and CD operations. So it's feasible that the DVD side could fail but the CD side remain working. Someone might want to correct me on this.

Comment: Yes, I can read DVDs.